# Grails Spring Security Shiro, how to create 2 login forms with 2 different authentication success urls?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working a project that leverages Spring Security Shiro. I would like to configure the application to have 2 different login forms with 2 different authentication success urls. What is the best way to perform this? I looked at the documentation but have not seen any solutions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way was to override the AuthenticationSuccessHandler with a custom one.

First create your success handler, my checks to see if the user is an admin user.

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication

import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession


class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    def requestCache
    boolean administrator = false

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        println administrator
        if(administrator){
            return "/admin"
        } else {
            return super.determineTargetUrl(request, response)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                        final Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            checkSetAdministratorUser(authentication)
            handle(request, response, authentication)
            super.clearAuthenticationAttributes(request)
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            // always remove the saved request
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response)
        }

    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response)

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl)
            return
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl)
    }

    def checkSetAdministratorUser(authentication){
        authentication.authorities.each(){ authority ->
            if(authority.authority == "ROLE_ADMIN")administrator = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then I had to define the success handler in the beans section of **resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    authenticationSuccessHandler(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
        requestCache = ref('requestCache')
        redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
    }
}
```

Then I was good to go. It worked well for my scenario.

Thanks: https://groggyman.com/2015/04/05/custom-authentication-success-handler-with-grails-and-spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the best way it's extending two separate `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and creating there two different configuration (two login page and two authentication success urls):

```
@Configuration
@Order(94)
public class WebSecurityConf1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/first-resources**").formLogin().successForwardUrl();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Order(95)
public class WebSecurityConf2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/second-resources**").formLogin().successForwardUrl();
    }
}
```

Note that `WebSecurityConf1` will be applied when `.antMatcher("/first-resources**")` is satisfied and the same for `WebSecurityConf2`. Also, configuration between `WebSecurityConf1` and `WebSecurityConf2` independent.